# Call child's method or cast parent to child in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
I have some STI structure like following:

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :criteria, :class_name => "Criterion", :order => :position
end

class Criterion < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Represents a criterion used to mark an assignment that
  # being the super class for all different criterias
  set_table_name "criteria" # set table name correctly
  belongs_to  :assignment
  validates_associated :assignment, :message => 'association is not strong with an assignment'
  validates_presence_of :assignment_id
  validates_numericality_of :assignment_id, :only_integer => true, :greater_than => 0, :message => "can only be whole number greater than 0"
  validates_uniqueness_of :criterion_name, :scope => :assignment_id, :message => 'is already taken'
  validates_presence_of :criterion_name,:assignment_id
end

class FlexibleCriterion < Criterion
  has_one :flexible_criterion_attribute, :class_name => "FlexibleCriterionAttribute"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :flexible_criterion_attribute
  default_scope :include => :flexible_criterion_attribute
end

class FlexibleCriterionAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :criterion, :class_name => "FlexibleCriterion"
  validates_presence_of :max
  validates_numericality_of :max, :message => "must be a number greater than 0.0", :greater_than => 0.0

  DEFAULT_MAX = 1

end
```

Alright, I have uploaded my current *working* codes. So basically the problem is:
When I use a method like criterion = assignment.criteria.find_or_create_by_criterion_name("AAA"), I will get an object of criterion. But I want cast this object to flexiblecriterion so that I can assign the value of criterion.flexible_criterion_attribute

```
Thx in advance!
```

Comment: Why do you have `has_many :part, :class_name => "Part"` instead of `has_many :parts`? Did you add a `type` column to the `parts` table. Why are your `dosomething` methods class methods? Your example/question doesn't really work together, so it's rather difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, Marcel. I guess my question is kinda confusing. But type column shall be added automatically, i mean i dont need to do that in the class, right? well, actually im not calling a method i created, i wanna call some function like find_by_name(),it is some self method, right? So i created this example. Im not sure if my explanation make the problem clear now?

Comment: your example can't works on your has_many. It's better if you clean it with a valid code.

Comment: I just uploaded my working copy, shall make more sense now,=P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `assignment.criteria.find_or_create_by_criterion_name("AAA")` returns a record in which `type` column has value `FlexibleCriterion`, it will automatically cast the object to `FlexibleCriterion`.
2. If you want to ensure that only `FlexibleCriterion` is returned, modify your finder like this: `assignment.criteria.find_or_create_by_criterion_name_and_type("AAA", 'FlexibleCriterion')`

Comment: Hi, Swanand, thx for the answer.
However, the 2nd point won't actually work, it will still return a :
#<Criterion id: 4, type: "FlexibleCriterion", criterion_name: "XXXTTT", assignment_id: 1, weight: nil, position: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2010-03-25 03:22:35", updated_at: "2010-03-25 03:22:35">

But you are right, at 1st. After it is created, it will always return a FlexibleCriterion.